# Use a VBA macro to replace individual characters in a word 2007 document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to write a macro that will replace specific characters in a selected string with other specific characters. That is, for example, I may want to replace all a's with b's, all b's with c's, and so on.

I wrote this test macro just to see if I could replace characters. It gets stuck in an infinite loop replacing the first character in the selection with "1".

```
Dim obChar As Range   'Define a range variable
For Each obChar In Selection.Characters
  obChar.Text = "1"
Next obChar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try a reversed loop:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = Selection.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
    Selection.Characters(i).Text = "1"
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, Giz...how the heck do I add a formatted comment with new code?

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for, but comments can be added like this: `Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Characters(i), Text:="This is a Comment"`

Comment: Sorry, I meant how can I add a reply to this thread and have all of the editing tools available that I had when I was creating the initial post?

Comment: The editing stuff is only available when you post an answer. But a limited set of formats works in comments, too. When adding a comment, click the help button on the right side, it will show you how you can format your comment